# Aptana and Canvas

Tags: canvas, autocomplete, aptana, html5-canvas

I'm new to Aptana and when I create new java-script file and  reference to a canvas tag id it seems that i don't have auto-complete for html5 canvas related function.

For example inside the java-script file:

```
var theCanvas = document.getElementById("canvasOne");
var context = theCanvas.getContext("2d");
```

when i write context. Aptana doesn't show Auto-complete suggestions for html5 canvas related functions like for example fillStyle.

How to show those auto-complete suggestions for html5 functions? or Aptana doesn't support them yet?

Comment: Did you try upgrading to 3.0.5 beta by using the beta channel? There were some errors with the 3.0.4 parser and this might be one of them

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to get Aptana autocomplete the new HTML5 APIs, but I use Komodo when I have to code some canvas stuff.

I took a shot of Komodo's autocomplete function : https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM9tL.png

Comment: Thank you, i just tried Komodo and it does exactly what i need